# SQL Counting and Average in one query

Tags: sql, count, xampp

I have the following tables:

- employee(ename,street,city) where ename is primary key
- company(cname, city) where cname is primary key
- works(ename,cname,salary) where ename,cname is primary key and ename references employee and cname references company.

For each employee name in the works table, I need to find the total number of companies they work for and the average salary.

I have some simple SQL experience, but this advanced aggregate and nested queries is pretty new to me.

I need one query to do this, so the output would be equal to the number of distinct enames in the works table, where each row in the output would have a number of jobs and a number - avg(salary), and i assume a employee name as well.

Any help or suggestions i could use would be appreciated.

This is a homework question, it's the last one on the list, all the other ones are working within the XAMMP environment, using PHPmyAdmin.

Thank you!

Comment: As you are asking for help with your homework, could you at least tell us what have you tried? The homework question has a very simple answer, so please make a sincere effort to answer it by yourself. Hint: it's a simple aggregate query and does not require nested queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select
    employee.ename
    , avg(works.salary) as avgsalary
    , count(company.cname) as numjobs
from
   employee
left join
    works
      on employee.ename = works.ename
left join
    companies
      on works.cname = companies.cname
group by employee.ename
```

Try that.
Mike

Comment: Hey Mike, thank you very much.  that worked perfectly, and helped me understand how join works as well as getting multiple aggregate functions.  i ran it with inner join instead of left join - does this affect anything? i cant see any ddifference in the result, but im sure somewhere along the line they differ somehow.

Thanks again

Comment: If you don't have a left join on works, in particular, and no relation exists, you won't see that employee name as it will eliminated from the inner join.  If for some reason a row in your company table gets deleted (it happens... Maybe key constraints aren't setup properly) then the count could be off even though the works relation exists.  Those are the two reasons I chose left join.

Comment: hmm. aweomse, thank you very much. made my schooling less stressful!

Comment: i see that group by <attribute> is needed here or else we only get one conglomerated row.  and i see the left join works bottom up, and can chunk together multiple tables, as if they were one table, but you still reference the attributes by using their distincitve parent tables names.  I guess here we could bypass the employee table all together and just join works and companies together, and do the same query, but if we wanted street and city of the employee, this way would work for sure.  is most of the power of this query coming from the group by <attr> clause?

does it seperat unique item?